# URL Rewriting in php CodeIgniter using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am working on a project in which url Rewriting was done. Here is the link of the old uri

```
http://www.mysite.pk/jobs/search/faisalabad/all-cats
```

But now in the new url I have changed it to

http://www.mysite.pk/jobs/pakistan/faisalabad/all-cats

what I want to do is to change the redirect all the url's whcih have `http://www.mysite.pk/jobs/search/` search after job in them to the

```
http://www.mysite.pk/jobs/pakistan/
```

Here is my code of the route

```
$route["jobs/pakistan"]="vacancies/search";
```

I have also done

```
$route["search/pakistan"]="vacancies/search";
```

My .htaccess file content is

but it is not working
Kindly Helpe me 
Thanks in advance

Comment: there is a very nice htaccess tester  that can help you to generate your htaccess here http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Do you really need the first rewrite condition and rule? There's a way which is more straightforward.

Comment: @berkyl yes i really need that i hope that works out

Comment: @Usama As far as I interpreted it you use it to provide the contents of some folders so they won't get rewritten to index.php, am I right?

Comment: i dont know in detail about it but i think it yes it is

Comment: @usama in this case you could use the sample in my updated answer. The two conditions in the lower part are for checking existing files and directorys. The route won't be rewritten to index.php when the file or directory actually exists and will have the same effect as the upper part of your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem are the missing placeholders. Without the placeholders your stated URL

```
http://www.mysite.pk/jobs/search/faisalabad/all-cats
```

won't match.

The correct route should look like this:

```
$route["jobs/pakistan/(:any)"]="vacancies/search";
$route["search/pakistan/(:any)"]="vacancies/search";
```

This way both jobs/pakistan and search/pakistan are working.

**Edit**

This RewriteRule will have the same effect when put in the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule ^jobs/search/(.*)?$ http://www.mysite.pk/jobs/pakistan/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Your .htaccess file then should look similar to this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

    ###

    RewriteRule ^jobs/search/(.*)?$ http://www.mysite.pk/jobs/pakistan/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Removes access to the system folder by users.
    # Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    # previously this would not have been possible.
    # 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    # Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

The RewriteRule has following scheme:

> RewriteRule [output] [original]

In this case when the "output" (url) starts with `jobs/search/` (the ^ marks the beginning and $ the end) everything after this will be redirected to the original. The `(.*)` marks a reference for any content and will be inserted in the origin in place of `$1`. The `[L,R=301]` marks the type of the redirect (the HTTP response status code 301 means Moved Permanently), the `L` means that after the route is met, the following lines won't be processed.

Comment: is their any way i cant rewrite it using .htaccess @berkul

Comment: @Usama Yes you could use a rewrite rule, but I would avoid that because this way you have to look at multiple places in case of an error instead of checking the routes.php and having an overview.

Comment: kindly guide me how can i do this using .htaccess

Comment: sorry for the late reply i was away for some personal reasons.i have implemented it but it is not working can you please see it again.

Comment: @usama could you please provide the directory structure and the content of your .htaccess? Where have you added the rewrite rule?

Comment: is their any way i can rwrite the url without changing the current .htaccess

Comment: @usama you can add the line provided in the answer before the rewrite condition in line 4 (right after rewriteengine on).